# Nested For Loops Numpy Array: Is vectorizing possible?

Tags: python, numpy

I been trying to speed up my code below which looks up an index, which will get a string from the list "name", and finally count the number of exact matches it has in two sections of data.

This process has been very slow. I read about replacing for loops when using numpy arrays but was not sure how to handle/approach creating a vectorized version with the regex matching.

```
x = np.empty([38000, 8000])  
y = np.empty([38000, 8000])  
for i in range(0, 38000):
    for j in range(0, 8000):
        x[i, j] = len(re.findall('\\b'+name[index[j]]+'\\b', data[i][1]))
        y[i, j] = len(re.findall('\\b'+name[index[j]]+'\\b', data[i][2]))
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated,

Comment: what do name, index and data look like?

Comment: Unless `name` itself contains regexs, it looks like you could first filter the possible candidate cells with simple string matching and then run regexs against the candidate cells...

Comment: `index = [ 0, 123, 454, ...] #1-by-8000`

index holds an index of name that is deemed interesting

`name = ['dog', 'cat', ...] `

name holds a large list of strings (1-by-50000) which we only want the index numbered values of.

Comment: String `count` or `np.char.count` are faster than `re.findall` if you don't need the `\b` separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorizing won't help you much here, but avoiding repeated work will:

```
patterns = [re.compile('\\b'+name[idx]+'\\b') for idx in index]
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, patt in enumerate(patterns):
        x[i, j] = len(patt.findall(row[1]))
        y[i, j] = len(patt.findall(row[2]))
```

Comment: and if `len(name) < len(index)`, compile the patterns before indexing.

Comment: You can compile the patterns at the start.

Comment: It's my understanding that the `re` module keeps a cache of compiled patterns, so pre-compiling might not help much.

Comment: I get a 40% speed up with `[len(pat.findall(i)) for i in x1]` compared to ` [len(re.findall('\\b'+'name'+'\\b',i)) for i in x1]``.

Comment: Interesting, maybe the large number of patterns overflows the `re` pattern cache? I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

vectorizing a function...

first define a function and vectorize it:

```
def count_words(word, sentence):
    return len(re.findall(r'\b%s\b'%word, sentence))

vcount_words = np.vectorize(count_words)
```

then apply (here words is array 800 element array and data is 3800X2 matrix)

```
vcount_words(names, data[:,:1])
```

smaller example so it fits here (5X3):

```
names = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
data = np.array([['aaa aaa aaa bbb dd', 'ee ff ccc ee ee dd bbb ee'],
                 ['aaa ccc dd aaa ff ff ee', 'dd ccc ee ccc dd ee ff'],
                 ['ee aaa ff ccc ff ee aaa dd bbb', 'aaa'],
                 ['ff ee ccc ccc', 'dd'],
                 ['ccc ee aaa dd', 'ccc bbb ee aaa bbb ff ee']])
x = vcount_words(names, data[:,:1])
# returns >>>
array([[3, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Adjust accordingly for your data.  This could be speed up by not recompiling the regex in the fuction (pre-compile and index into it).  I would also investigate numba whenever you are looping over numpy arrays with for loops.

But, this demonstrates the vectorize a function approach, you've already "accepted" and it's late.

Comment: The `vectorize` function does not speed up the code - it just wraps it in a way that facilitates broadcasting and other array tricks.

Comment: There is a `np.char` module that applies string operations to arrays of strings.  But it doesn't handle the fancier search patterns that `re` does.